# SSIS: How To Use Deployment Utility Using A Single Package Configuration File

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create a deployment utility for a solution using a single package configuration file shared across packages.
when I try to build the solution to create the deployment utility, the build process fails saying that the package configuration file already exists....

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Is there an option to overwrite that file?  There are similar settings in Reporting services concerning datasources...

Don't know about that though - we set an env variable on the server which points to the sql instance with the ssis config db and then the package finds the ssis configurations database in that instance.

Comment: i'm doing the same except using a xml file instead of an env variable. The accepted wisdom seems to be not to use the utility!

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be for complex deployments that have many file dependencies to be moved around.  I just use the 'save a copy as' dialog.  Your scenario is a bit different since you do need to save the xml file on the server.  I made a util to shuffle ssis config data around.